# Angular application opens in electron, but not in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, node-modules, require

In the main.js file I have declared:

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true
}
```

So, I can open the application in electron, but in browser I have an error:

```
TypeError: window.require is not a function
```

In my component I had an error with require electron and now I use:

```
declare var window: Window;
declare global {
  interface Window {
    process: any;
    require: any;
  }
}
const electron = window.require('electron');
```

I have tried a lot of methods, but the browser does not recognise the window.require function.

Comment: why you're calling `const electron = window.require('electron');` in app?

Comment: because I need to pass maximize/minimize and close functions from the component to main.js where electron is initialized.

Comment: So if you're running electron in app then how it can work in browser?

Comment: that's why window.require error appears in browser?

Comment: Maybe remove the 'window.' and import it as you would import any other module?

Comment: If you want app to run on browser you can't use electron inside.

Comment: Ok, thank you @PrzemyslawJanBeigert.